# Docker file import another image and install

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a python app which is using [this tool](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DiscordChatExporter/wiki/Docker-usage-instructions) And i can't figure out how to do it.

I used `FROM tyrrrz/discordchatexporter:stable` but then how can i run the commands from it. I am thinking of using a `subprocess.Popen` to run the commands, Can someone show me how to add it the dockerfile and how to reach it (path + command)

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-slim as base

# Setup env
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1

FROM base AS python-deps

# Install pipenv and compilation dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc

# Install python dependencies in /.venv
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --deploy

FROM base AS runtime

# Copy virtual env from python-deps stage
COPY --from=python-deps /.venv /.venv
ENV PATH="/.venv/bin:$PATH"

# Create and switch to a new user
RUN useradd --create-home az
WORKDIR /home/az
USER az

# Install application into container
COPY . .

# Run the application
CMD python main.py
```

Comment: There's no way to combine images or call binaries in one image from another.  If you need to invoke those binaries you need to `RUN` some sort of command in your own image to install them (`pip install`, `apt-get install`, `curl` depending on how it's packaged).

Comment: @DavidMaze I did not know that thanks. I want to run a `dotnet something.dll` along side my python is it possible? because dotnet is not installed by default.